# Generar arrays dinámicamente y añadir elementos de la misma forma

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo que guardar la diferencia de X archivos (páginas de un pdf) y necesito que en cada array (uno por página) se guarden las diferencias de esa página.

**He conseguido generar arrays vacíos dinámicamente, pero mi problema es ¿cómo hacer el push a esos arrays dinámicamente también?**

El contenido que debe ser "dinámico", ya que no conozco el número total de páginas puede variar, es el de los if anidados que muestro en el código:

```
    //genera dinámicamente los arrays en los que se guardaran diferencias de cada página (el número total de páginas es allPages.length)

    for (i=1; i<=allPages.length; i++) {
        eval("diffPage"+i+"="+"[]");
    }

    var pairs = []; //Ej. var combinations = ["texto1","texto2","4"];

    for (var x=0; x<pairs.length; x++){

        var diff = recognizeTerms(comb[x], 5, 50); //diferencias de todas las combinaciones posibles

        for (y=1; y<allPages.length; y++) {

            for (z=0; z<diff.length; z++) {

                //A partir de aquí:
                //¿Hay alguna manera de hacer este guardado en arrays dinámico?
                //Ya que se deben guardar las diferencias de cada página en un array

                if (combinations[x][2] == 1) {
                    if (diffPage1.includes(diff[z]) == false) { //comprueba que el string no existe ya en el array de diferencias
                        diffPage1.push(diff[z]);
                    }
                } 
                if (combinations[x][2] == 2) {
                    if (diffPage2.includes(diff[z]) == false) {
                        diffPage2.push(diff[z]);
                    }
                } 
                if (combinations[x][2] == 3) {
                    if (diffPage3.includes(diff[z]) == false) {
                        diffPage3.push(diff[z]);
                    }
                } 
                if (combinations[x][2] == 4) {
                    if (diffPage4.includes(diff[z]) == false) {
                        diffPage4.push(diff[z]);
                    }
                }

                //sucesivos if ... (tantos como números de página haya), por ello necesito que sean dinámicos esos if
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar los arrays en un array. De ese modo solucionas dos cosas: no usas `eval`, que **siempre** es una mala idea, y sabes el número de arrays que tienes:

Por tanto, tu primer bucle queda así:

```
let diffPages=[];
for (let i=0; i<allPages.length; i++) {
    diffPages.push([]);
}
```

y tu bucle más interno queda así:

```
        for (z=0; z<diff.length; z++) {

          for (let page=0;page<diffPages.length;page++) {

            if (combinations[x][2] == page) {
              if (diffPages[page].includes(diff[z]) == false) { //comprueba que el string no existe ya en el array de diferencias
                    diffPages[page].push(diff[z]);
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Y el bucle  `for (y=1; y<allPages.length; y++) {` te sobra porque no estás usando `y` para nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y explicación, tu solución es perfecta!